# Calculus A Level Equation Of Normal To Curve Defined in Parametric Form with Trig Functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric, tangent-line

guys how are you doing today? Can you take some time to look over this equation of a curve defined in terms of $\theta $ and suggest how I can find the equation of the normal at the point $(a, \frac{a\pi}{2} - a)? $ In other words, finding the normal when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\,$.

$$  x(\theta) = a(\theta - sin(\theta)) \\y(\theta) = a(1 - cos(\theta)) $$

I'm trying to rewrite the parametric equations in terms of $\theta$ so that I can equate the two equations making a Cartesian equation with just x and y. Then I can take derivative with respect to x.

$$ y(\theta) = a(1 - cos(\theta))\\\frac{y}{a} = 1 - cos(\theta)\\1-\frac{y}{a} = cos(\theta) \\ \theta = arccos(1-\frac{y}{a})$$

Rewriting the parametric equation $x(\theta) = a(\theta-sin(\theta))$ is very hard to do.

I need to find the slope of the tangent at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is the slope at $(a, \frac{a\pi}{2} - a)$ then I can find the normal, right?

Comment: You don’t need to isolate $\theta$, you can directly find $\frac{dx}{d\theta }$ and $\frac{dy}{d\theta }$ and divide the second by the first to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: It’s not only difficult, but impossible to come up with an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ since it essentially involves solving the $x(\theta)$ expression for $\theta$. You can arrive at an implicit equation in the form $f(x,y)=0$ with the work that you’ve done so far, but it’s much easier to work with the parameterization directly.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct coordinates of the point? It appears that they’ve been swapped compared the the parametric equations that you have here.